# How to create a directory/folder by php?

Tags: php, directory

When I create a category in my CMS, I want to create its directory/folder in an image directory.

Can I create a directory or folder with php?

Can anyone tell me how please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want [`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php):

```
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir");
```

or

```
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);
```

If you want it to be private to the user creating it.

Answer (score 1):

[mkdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Answer (score 0):

Small change addition

```
if (is_dir("/path/to/my/dir") == false) {
         /* 700 -> permissions , true -> recursive*/
         if (mkdir("/path/to/my/dir",700,true) == false) {
             /* your error handling */
        }
}
```